# Lindeberg condition of order $2k$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Prove that if $ (X_n),\: n \ge 1$ are independent r.v.s with $  E X_n = 0, E X_n^2 = \sigma_n^2$ which obey central limit theorem and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\bigg(\frac{S_n }{\sqrt{s_n}}\bigg)^{2k} = \frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!},$$

then  $ (X_n) $ obeys a Lindeberg condition of order $2k$, i.e. $$\sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{|x| > \varepsilon s_n}|x|^{2k}dF_j(x) = o(s_{n}^{2k}),\: \quad   \forall   \varepsilon  > 0,   $$
where  $  s_n^2 = E S_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2. $

Here is what I've got so far.

1. Lindeberg condition of order $r > 2$ is equivalent to Lyapunov condition of order $r \;(\sum_{j = 1}^n E|X_j|^r = o(s_n^r))$.

Proof:

Clearly,  Lyapunov condition implies Lindeberg condition. Suppose now that $$\sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{|x| > \varepsilon s_n}|x|^{2k}dF_j(x) = o(s_{n}^{2k}).\:  $$ Then 
\begin{multline*} \sum_{j = 1}^n E|X_j|^r \le  \sum_{j = 1}^n E((\varepsilon s_n)^{r-2}X_j^2I\{|X_j|\le \varepsilon s_n\} + |X_j|^rI\{|X_j|>\varepsilon s_n\})\le \\ \le  \varepsilon ^{r-2}s_n^r + o(s_n^r) \:\; \forall  \varepsilon  > 0 .\: \end{multline*}

2. $$\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!} = (2k - 1)!! = E N^{2k},\: \quad  N \sim N(0,\,1).\:    $$

   It would be logical to assume that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\bigg(\frac{S_n}{s_n}\bigg)^{2k} =E N^{2k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\bigg(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{s_n}}\bigg)^{2k} , $$ but I don't know whether it's true and how it would help.

   Could anyone hive me a hint for solving this? Thank you!